# Rebuilding/Updating kernel module

Tags: c, linux, kernel-module, rebuild

Hey there,
following problem:
I'm using a rather weird linux distro here at work (Centos 5) which seems to have an older kernel (or at least some differences in the kernel) and you can't simply update it.
The program I need to install needs a function crypto_destro_tfm (and prob some more, but this is the only error at this point) which is included in the file linux/crypto/api.c - so I assume its in the kernel module crypto_api. Problem is: On my distro, I don't even have an crypto/api.c and even though I do have a module crypto_api.ko it seems that this function isn't in there.

My plan is the following: Take the crypto_api from a newer linux distro and then compile it and load the module into my centos.

Now I hope that some of you can tell me what I need to do to rebuild and replace that module. Of course I do have all the source files from a newer kernel. (Just to remind you: I can't simply recompile and use a newer kernel, b/c centos sucks in this way)
Thank you

FWIW: Here's the exact error

WARNING: "crypto_destroy_tfm" [/home/Chris/digsig-patched/digsig_verif.ko] undefined!

Comment: Why can't you update the kernel? Aren't you root?

Comment: See [PATCH staging, rtl81xx: Fix build problems when CONFIG_CRYPTO=n](http://kerneltrap.org/mailarchive/linux-driver-devel/2010/5/28/6885249), is it relevant to your problem?

Comment: If there are no kernel updates, and you can't run a vanilla kernel, then you should be adding "migrate to a different linux distribution ASAP" to your todo list.

Comment: I can't update to a vanilla kernel as the CentOS update policy is kind of weird. I don't like it either, wouldn't use it myself, but it's at work.

Comment: (Does not matter where it's at.)

Answer (score 0):

There is a good chance backporting API change in an older kernel will lead to a cascade of problem. Let's suppose you backport crypto api of version 2.6.Y to your local version, 2.6.X

Now you have the following situation :

- module crypto api export 2.6.Y functions
- your external module might be Happy with that situation
- all other module that depends on version 2.6.X of the crypto API will complain.

But wait, I can backport recent kernel code into all the modules that complain, and here we go... Oops, but then we have the former situation, but now each backported module might trigger a similar situation.

If you can't update the CentOS kernel, because the CentOS kernel has a lot of custom code you are afraid to loose when going with a "vanilla" kernel, then you may find that it is an easier task to "downgrade" your external module :

- Look at the current crypto API (for example using lxr.linux.no)
- Look at your kernel version of this API
- Try to see how the new API could be replaced with call to the old API to provide a similar function.
- Modify your external module to use the old API instead of the new one.

In any case, you may not be able to replace your kernel with a vanilla one, but you should at least be able to rebuild it, and then to patch it and rebuild it etc... If you can't do this simple task, then I don't think backporting anything will be successful.

Comment: I can see def. see your point. But from what I've seen in the code that ne newer version is basically only expanded with some new functions. I therefore think that backporting it will not come up with big troubles (maybe a little bit of adjusting for the new functions is needed) - and therefore I want to at least give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading the SRC RPM from a newer version of CentOS which has the module and recompile the RPM on your CentOS 5:

```
rpmbuild --rebuild kernel-X.XX-X.src.rpm
```

I don't have a copy of CentOS to compare with so you will want to read the man page on rpm/rpmbuild, but I've found recompiling the whole package which includes the kernel and all it's modules to be safer than trying to just porting one module from a newer kernel.  I do this occasionally on Debian/Ubuntu when I need a newer package for something.